# Does using a verifiable secret sharing scheme ensure robustness of a protocol if it is secure under the semi-honest adversarial model

Tags: reference-request, multiparty-computation, secret-sharing

Consider a protocol $\pi$ which uses a linear secret sharing scheme like that of Shamir secret sharing. Further assume that the protocol $\pi$ has been proven to be secure (correctness and privacy) under the semi-honest adversarial model. If we replace the secret sharing scheme with a verifiable secret sharing scheme, will the protocol $\pi$ then be secure even under the malicious adversarial model? That is, can we say that the robustness of $\pi$ is implicit?  If yes, please provide a reference. If no, please help me understand as to in which cases will the above not be true.

Comment: Not necessarily (though it certainly _can_ be). ​ No. ​ This is a "just do it" construction, like [the](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24630/991)se  [two](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18302/991). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Why didn't you post this as an answer?